# Query External Object filtering by Date or DateTime dataType

Tags: soql, data-types, externalobjects, sharepoint, files-connect

first time ever writing here, hope anyone can help me:
We're working with Salesforce Files Connect, currently configured and working with SharePoint.
Users can browse files by certain filters we're passing to the external data source (SP), basically strings datatypes.
Now we're trying to add two Dates (or DateTime if necessary to make everything work) so we can filter based on date ranges.
At first we tried with the custom property "CreatedDate__c" created together with the ExternalObject which worked wonderfully.

[image: first search]

However when we try to access a new custom CrawledProperty, for ex. "WR_OnAirMax__c" we get this error:

> EXTERNAL_OBJECT_EXCEPTION: The "WR_OnAirMax__c" field is of type date or date/time, but the value from the external system is "11/10/2020 8:00:00 AM". Contact your administrator for help.

Looking [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.admin_files_connect_sp_custom_props.htm&type=5) in the docs, it seems that we have to create 2 CustomProperties on our external object, one Text for search purposes and one Date for Filtering purposes.

[image: obj info]

> The Sharepoint Search service returns all metadata from Office documents as strings, so corresponding external object fields must be set to the Text type.
> Dates are returned in the format, MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss AM/PM, (for example, “3/31/2015 9:59:00 PM”). To query on fields using the Date type, the external object must include a corresponding Date field for filtering, and a Text field for selecting.

Which makes us actually query now the dates...

[image: almost!]

However it seems that no matter what we pass to the where clause's Date field, it doesn't return anything.

[image: no query result]

Anyone can point us anywhere? Thank you

Comment: Are you using SharePoint, or SharePoint Online? The docs say you can't filter dates on SharePoint online for some reason...

Comment: SharePoint Online. I didn't even think it would make any difference since we always worked with online versions. Not to mention that on FilesConnect documentation doesn't mention anything about that.. or at least i didn't see any hint. So, solution might be getting records and cycling through, manually checking the date value and sort out the ones i need?

Comment: I don't know enough to be sure, but the docs you linked to say that at the very bottom of the page, unless I'm misinterpreting it.

Comment: That's my concern! It's not THAT clear, though i guess you're right. Every other field we're using as query fields/where clauses are strings. These two were the only Dates... Seems that only default CrawledProperties such as CreatedDate__c can be actually filtered. Thanks for the help anyway :)